# Embed Variables not parsing in time in embed placed inside of Playa Parents tag

Tags: channel-entries, safecracker, playa, parse-order

I’m currently trying to add a safecracker form that either creates a new entry or edits the existing one depending on whether or not the `CURRENT_USER` has made one or not. Part of this also requires I place the form inside of a `exp:channel:entries` tag. Now, when I’m using the code below, I find that my embed variable for segment_id is not parsing properly, but instead, it looks like it’s parsing after everything else and actually returning `{entry_id}` as the embed variable.

```
{exp:playa:parents channel="implementation_notes" status="not closed" author_id="CURRENT_USER"}
  {if no_parents}{embed="embeds/_implementation_notes_form_create" segment_id="{child:entry_id}"}{/if}
  {embed="embeds/_implementation_notes_form_update" segment_id="{entry_id}"}
{/exp:playa:parents}
```

Anyone have a suggestion how to get around this without having to refactor the original developer’s code too much?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will run into issues nesting the form inside the channel entries tag, since the both share some of the var variables. Not sure about the EE embed though, as I don't use them anymore in favor of Stash.

So...

My recommendation would be to use Stash to include the form inside the loop, but parse it beforehand so there are no conflicts.

```
{exp:stash:set parse_tags="yes"}

    {stash:safecracker}
        [YOUR HTML/TAGS HERE]
    {/stash:safecracker}

{/exp:stash:set}

{exp:channel:entries}

    {!-- Short syntax for the Dev branch --}
    {exp:stash:safecracker}

    {!-- Legacy/original syntax for the master branch --}
    {exp:stash:get name="safecracker"}

    {!-- Just to be clear, no need to use both tags. Choose one. --}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

You will likely need more complicated logic than this, but the same principal applies. Simply change the parse order to fit your own needs - Stash is the best tool for that.

Comment: This was the solution that I arrived at towards the end, myself. It’s a shame that this collection of addons can get so convoluted. As much as I love Stash, it can be a bit daunting to introduce it to a client’s team.